# Embed Excel in JavaFx

Tags: excel, javafx-8

Is there a library that allows for the display of an excel sheet/workbook inside a FX GUI? It does not need to be modifiable.

I am using [apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) for the reading and writing of documents.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an update on how I solved this. I used [controlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/)'s SpreadsheetView to display the excel sheet I read using the poi library. All that was required was to read the sheet and build up the data for the view. I added the code below.

```
/**
 * This class allows for the displaying of excel files within a window by
 * utilizing SpreadsheetView from controlsFX and the reading capabilities of     the POI library.
 * 
 * Only usable for .xlsx files
 *  
 * @author TM
 *
 */
public class ExcelView {

    /**
     * Path to Excel
     */
    private String filePath;

    private int sheetIndex;

    private boolean editible;

    private FileInputStream inStream;
    private XSSFWorkbook poiWorkbook;
    private XSSFSheet poiSheet;

    private SpreadsheetView theView;

    public ExcelView(String path, int sheetIndex ,boolean editable){
        filePath  =path;
        this.editible  =editable;
        this.sheetIndex  =sheetIndex;
    }

    public ExcelView(String path, int sheetIndex){
        filePath  =path;
        this.editible  =false;
        this.sheetIndex = sheetIndex;
    }

    private void initializeView() throws Exception{
        GridBase grid = excelToGrid();

        theView = new SpreadsheetView(grid);
        theView.setEditable(editible);
    }

    public SpreadsheetView getView() throws Exception{
        initializeView();
        return theView;
    }

    public void showInNewWindow(){
        Parent root;
        try {

        initializeView();

        root = theView;
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle(new File(filePath).getName());
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 450));

        stage.getIcons().addAll(ResourceLoader.getIcons("Excel.ico"));      

        stage.show();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the values in the view. This may happen after the Excel file has been 
 * modified after the initial reading.
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public void updateView() throws Exception{
    GridBase newgrid = excelToGrid();

    theView.setGrid(newgrid);
}

/**
 * Creates a {@link GridBase} object from the excel file located at the path
 * @return
 * @throws Exception - when opening the file
 */
private GridBase excelToGrid() throws Exception{

    // Read the Excel document and collect the rows
    openBook();
    poiSheet = poiWorkbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);

    int[] size =  getSize();
    GridBase grid = new GridBase(size[0], size[1]);

    ObservableList<ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell>> rows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    Row poiRow;
    Cell cell;
    String value;
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = poiWorkbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    for (int row = 0; row < grid.getRowCount(); ++row) {
        final ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        poiRow = poiSheet.getRow(row);
        for (int column = 0; column < grid.getColumnCount(); ++column) {

            cell = poiRow.getCell(column);
            value = ExcelUtils.cellStringValue(evaluator,cell);

            list.add(SpreadsheetCellType.STRING.createCell(row, column, 1, 1,value));
        }
        rows.add(list);
    }
    grid.setRows(rows);

    closeBook();

    return grid;
}

/**
 * Calculates the number of rows and columns in the sheet by looping 
 * and reading all the things :) 
 * @return the size as int[{rows, cols}]
 */
private int[] getSize(){

    int numRows = 0;
    int numCols =0;

    int nullRowCounter = 0;
    int nullColCounter = 0;

    int maxNullRows = 6;
    int maxNullCols = 6;

    Row row;
    Cell cell;
    int localColCounter;

    while(true){

        row= poiSheet.getRow(numRows);
        numRows++;

        // Check row...
        if(row == null){
            nullRowCounter++;
        }
        else{
            nullRowCounter = 0;
            // If row not null, check columns...
            localColCounter = 0;
            while(true){
                cell = row.getCell(localColCounter);
                localColCounter++;
                if(cell==null){
                    nullColCounter++;
                }else{
                    nullColCounter = 0;
                }

                if(nullColCounter == maxNullCols){
                    // reached max null cells
                    localColCounter -= maxNullCols;

                    if(localColCounter >  numCols)
                        numCols = localColCounter;

                    break;
                    // go to next row...
                }

            }
        }

        if(nullRowCounter == maxNullRows){
            // reached max null rows
            numRows -= maxNullRows;

            break;

        }
    }
    return new int[]{numRows, numCols};

}

private void openBook() throws Exception{
    try {
        File myFile = new File(filePath);
        inStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);

        poiWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook (inStream);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}

private void closeBook() throws Exception{


    try {
        poiWorkbook.close();
        inStream.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This seems likes a very fine example! Maybe you could improve it by detecting the type of data you have in Excel and use the SpreadsheetCellType according to it. You can also detect the Excel format and set it in the cell if you want to.

Comment: @Maxoudela Thanks :)  I am currently converting all cell values to Strings with a custom method which allows for the handling of null cells as well. But I believe changing that to you suggestions will result in a much better display. I will add it to my todo list and update the answer when I'm finished.